# SearchController Searchbar background color properties change navigation bar color too in ios Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

Please check this I have tried but it changes whole color but not changes searchbar background.

```
1. try with navigation searchcontroller searchbar
2. my uisearchcontroller searchbar 
1.
     if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
          self.navigationItem.searchController=nil;
          self.navigationItem.searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor=nil;
          self.navigationItem.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor=nil;
          self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchControllerInvoice;
          [self.searchControllerInvoice.searchBar setBackgroundColor:UIColor.redColor];
          [self.searchControllerInvoice.searchBar setBarTintColor:UIColor.yellowColor];
          [self.searchControllerInvoice.searchBar setTintColor:UIColor.greenColor];
     } else {
          self.getInvoiceTable.tableHeaderView = self.searchControllerInvoice.searchBar;
     }
     OR
2.
     if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
          self.navigationItem.searchController=nil;
          self.navigationItem.searchController.searchBar.backgroundColor=nil;
          self.navigationItem.searchController.searchBar.barTintColor=nil;
          self.navigationItem.searchController = self.searchControllerInvoice;
          [self.navigationItem.searchController.searchBar setBackgroundColor:UIColor.redColor];
          [self.navigationItem.searchController.searchBar setBarTintColor:UIColor.yellowColor];
          [self.navigationItem.searchController.searchBar setTintColor:UIColor.greenColor];
     } else {
          self.getInvoiceTable.tableHeaderView = self.searchControllerInvoice.searchBar;
     }
```

I have try background, bartint, tint but the issue is still there 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the serachBar's backgroundImage property to a one pixel UIImage with the desired color?

Comment: Yes i will try background image like searchControllr.searchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImag new]; but still this is not working for me

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant. I mean like `searchBar.backgroundImage = [UIImage imageWithColor:color ofSize:CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)];` with `+ (UIImage*)imageWithColor:(UIColor*)color ofSize:(CGSize)size
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, NO, 0);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [color setFill];
    CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height));
    UIImage* image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}`.

Comment: I will try this i hope this helps me thank you

Comment: Hello D. Mika i'm not getting can you please answer this separately so i can understand too. Thank You

Comment: Hii i try with both approach but it still not working 
self.navigationItem.searchController.searchBar.backgroundImage = [self imageWithColor:UIColor.blackColor ofSize:CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)];
     self.searchControllerInvoice.searchBar.backgroundImage = [self imageWithColor:UIColor.blackColor ofSize:CGSizeMake(1.0, 1.0)];

Comment: Anyone have any solution for this because it still not working for me !!Thank You